# Ruby to decrypt PHP encrypted text

Tags: ruby, encryption

I'd like to use Ruby to decrypt a string that's encrypted with PHP. The same decryption logic works fine with PHP, but the Ruby code returns garbage.

The working PHP example:

```php
<?php

$_RIJNDAEL_KEY_ = "uUxJIpSKMbOQQdtm6Y4rPEXeE9TAKUns";
$_RIJNDAEL_IV_ = "PiToVoRjwlg8UwxUxQKI4w==";
$ciphertext = 'T353/s48iKzAf61b2dCOnqUApYa4xxjye8he4oAtJHyyCKl8sCbI33hfP6IqOsQZEIWeQBCsvy97xwJMPD8RwLG4J0wgX9Ihlti1vMar+5nrLrCR4lAfZcoJopoBt1JVnDAojLW+y0S0y5c4GCdB8YrHzj4jv70dg3yX8DxlAWE=';


$content = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $_RIJNDAEL_KEY_, base64_decode($ciphertext), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $_RIJNDAEL_IV_);
echo $content . "\n";

?>
```

The not-working Ruby example:

```ruby
require "openssl"
require "digest"
require "uri"
require "base64"

data = Base64.decode64("T353/s48iKzAf61b2dCOnqUApYa4xxjye8he4oAtJHyyCKl8sCbI33hfP6IqOsQZEIWeQBCsvy97xwJMPD8RwLG4J0wgX9Ihlti1vMar+5nrLrCR4lAfZcoJopoBt1JVnDAojLW+y0S0y5c4GCdB8YrHzj4jv70dg3yX8DxlAWE=")
key = Base64.decode64('uUxJIpSKMbOQQdtm6Y4rPEXeE9TAKUns')
iv = Base64.decode64('PiToVoRjwlg8UwxUxQKI4w==')
aes = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-128-ECB')

aes.decrypt
aes.padding = 0
aes.key = key
aes.iv = iv

plain = aes.update(data) + aes.final
puts plain
```

Could anyone shed some light ? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you run base64 decode on the key and the iv in the Ruby version, but not in the PHP version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything here is correct. But.
It is necessary to use AES-**256**-ECB in your example.

Here the code which is [runnable](http://repl.it/9MW):

```
require "openssl"
require "digest"
require "uri"
require "base64"

data = 'T353/s48iKzAf61b2dCOnqUApYa4xxjye8he4oAtJHyyCKl8sCbI33hfP6IqOsQZEIWeQBCsvy97xwJMPD8RwLG4J0wgX9Ihlti1vMar+5nrLrCR4lAfZcoJopoBt1JVnDAojLW+y0S0y5c4GCdB8YrHzj4jv70dg3yX8DxlAWE='
key = "uUxJIpSKMbOQQdtm6Y4rPEXeE9TAKUns"
#iv = 'PiToVoRjwlg8UwxUxQKI4w=='
aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :ECB)

#  Without padding checksum|4033315172 will be truncated!
aes.padding = 0
aes.decrypt
aes.key = key
#aes.iv = iv

plain = aes.update(data.unpack('m')[0]) + aes.final
```

After `decrypt` I've got the following:

```
=> "date_add|2015-01-28 01:36:17\xC2\xA4id_lang|1\xC2\xA4id_currency|1\xC2\xA4id_guest|12165\xC2\xA4id_connections|10668\xC2\xA4checksum|4033315172\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

Next. Without zero-padding in this example, last character of `checksum` will be truncated. If possible, don't use **EBC** mode. [Here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#label-Choosing+an+IV) is why.

And finally, you don't need IV in this example.
Good luck!

Comment: Genius! but may I ask why use AES-256-ECB is the Ruby example ?

Comment: @inthecloud Here are good readings about this: 
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864700/part-ii-how-to-make-ruby-aes-256-cbc-and-php-mcrypt-rijndael-128-play-well-toge
-  http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/php_aes.asp