# how to duplicate openssl_encrypt?

Tags: php, encryption, go

I was hoping someone had already implemented this in golang as I am far from even good at cryptography. However in porting a project from php to golang I have run into an issue with porting the openssl_encrypt method found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php). I have also dug into the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/8633685675692e9a926cf9f97b1c406c37497ddf/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L5168-L5246) a little with no avail.

Here is the method I have [implemented](https://play.golang.org/p/bAlV--IYbY) in golang. which gives me the output

```
lvb7JwaI4OCYUrdJMm8Q9uDd9rIILnvbZKJb/ozFbwCmLKkxoJN5Zf/ODOJ/RGq5
```

Here is the output I need when using php.

```
lvb7JwaI4OCYUrdJMm8Q9uDd9rIILnvbZKJb/ozFbwDV98XaJjvzEjBQp7jc+2DH
```

And here is the function I used to generate it with php.

```
$data = "This is some text I want to encrypt";
$method = "aes-256-cbc";
$password = "This is a really long key and su";
$options = 0;
$iv = "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM";

echo openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $password, $options, $iv);
```

To me it looks like it is very close and I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: The PHP output is actually `lvb7JwaI4OCYUrdJMm8Q9uDd9rIILnvbZKJb/ozFbwDV98XaJjvzEjBQp7jc+2DH` (Note the last symbol is missing).

Comment: @JasonCoco would you care to elaborate? Like i said above I don't know a lot about crypto. But that is besides the point this is the encryption that a third party uses. However if you link me to some articles on why using CBC is bad ill look into it and try and change some peoples minds.

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad, use cbc, don't use ecb, which you weren't using at all :) Apologizes for the misleading comment and I promise to sleep more before commenting in the future!

Comment: @JasonCoco no problem at all just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close, but you had the padding wrong.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1870754/3108853) (and the PHP docs), PHP uses the default OpenSSL padding behavior, which is to use the required number of padding bytes as the padding byte value.

The only change I made was:

```
copy(plaintextblock[length:], bytes.Repeat([]byte{uint8(extendBlock)}, extendBlock))
```

You can see the full updated code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/WFzm4QRDVC).

Comment: Thank you so much, Been trying to figure this one out for a while. The answer you linked to helped me understand padding better.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Just FYI, looks like you *always* have to use padding, so you might have to change your code some to still use padding even when the input plaintext is exactly a multiple of the block size.

Comment: Thank you very much! Saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

Others beat me to the answer while I was playing with it, but I have a "better" fixed version of your example code that also takes into account that padding is always required (at least to emulate what the php code does).

It also shows the `openssl` command line that you'd use to do the same thing, and if available runs it (of course the playground won't).

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    const input = "This is some text I want to encrypt"
    fmt.Println(opensslCommand(input))
    fmt.Println(aesCBCenctypt(input))
}

func aesCBCenctypt(input string) string {
    // Of course real IVs should be from crypto/rand
    iv := []byte("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM")
    // And real keys should be from something like PBKDF2, RFC 2898.
    // E.g. use golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2 to turn a
    // "passphrase" into a key.
    key := []byte("This is a really long key and su")

    // Make sure the block size is a multiple of aes.BlockSize
    // Pad to aes.BlockSize using the pad length as the padding
    // byte. If we would otherwise need no padding we instead
    // pad an entire extra block.
    pad := (aes.BlockSize - len(input)%aes.BlockSize)
    if pad == 0 {
        pad = aes.BlockSize
    }
    data := make([]byte, len(input)+pad)
    copy(data, input)
    for i := len(input); i < len(input)+pad; i++ {
        data[i] = byte(pad)
    }

    cb, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error NewCipher():", err)
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(cb, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(data, data)
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data)
}

// Just for comparison, don't do this for real!
func opensslCommand(input string) string {
    iv := []byte("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM")
    key := []byte("This is a really long key and su")

    args := []string{"enc", "-aes-256-cbc", "-base64"}
    // "-nosalt", "-nopad"
    args = append(args, "-iv", fmt.Sprintf("%X", iv))
    args = append(args, "-K", fmt.Sprintf("%X", key))

    cmd := exec.Command("openssl", args...)
    // Show how you could do this via the command line:
    fmt.Println("Command:", strings.Join(cmd.Args, " "))

    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(input)
    result, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        if e, ok := err.(*exec.Error); ok && e.Err == exec.ErrNotFound {
            // openssl not available
            return err.Error() // XXX
        }
        // some other error, show it and the (error?) output and die
        fmt.Println("cmd error:", err)
        log.Fatalf("result %q", result)
    }
    // Strip trailing '\n' and return it.
    if n := len(result) - 1; result[n] == '\n' {
        result = result[:n]
    }
    return string(result)
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/rzP7MzYqBH)