# Sagepay crypt field in Ruby

Tags: ruby, opayo

How should I encode 'Crypt' field to make it valid with protocol 3.00 in Ruby? Currently my string looks as follow:

```
=hidden_field_tag 'Crypt', Base64.encode64('VendorTxCode=406227821909&Amount=32.00&Currency=GBP&Description=Test&SuccessURL=http://example.com/success.php&FailureURL=http://example.com/fail.php&BillingSurname=Smith&BillingFirstnames=John&BillingAddress1=123 Main Street&BillingCity=Anywhere&BillingPostCode=29555&BillingCountry=UK&DeliverySurname=Smith&DeliveryFirstnames=John&DeliverAddress1=123 Main Street&DeliveryCity=Anywhere&DeliveryPostCode=29555&DeliveryCountry=UK')
```

But each time I get this error as response:

```
Status Detail:  5068 : The encryption method is not supported by this protocol version.
```

Thanks in advance, 
Oskar

Comment: Have you checked the docs here? https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/1151/download-document/FORMProtocolandIntegrationGuidelinesV3%200.pdf, it says "The Crypt field should contain all the other transaction information (see the next section) in plain text as Name=Value fields separated 
by ‘&’ characters. This string should then be encrypted using the AES/CBC/PCKS#5 algorithm and the pre-registered Encryption 
password, then subsequently Base64 encoded to allow safe transport in an HTML form." So its not just encoding with Base64

Comment: I was using Encryptor gem and then base64 encode and it doesn't work also :-(. I was using [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374550/rijndael-aes-128-encryption-decryption-in-ruby this answer (at the bottom) with the same values except of message and key :-). Iv was the same.

Comment: have you checked sagepay docs? I think that the general information on what needs to be done is there, despite what programming languague you use.

Comment: If you solved this, you should say so or update your q. If the only answer fixed it, please mark as so

Answer (score 0):

The AES encrypted string should be prefixed with '@' in order to identify the encryption method to the Sage Pay gateway. Conversely, the '@' should be removed before decoding.

Also using AES, there is no requirement for base64 encoding....